# Printing HashMap of HashMaps : Map.Entry or java8

Tags: java, hashmap, entryset

I have a method which returns out hashmap of hashmaps

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> mapofmaps = abcd(<String>, <Integer>);
```

I am trying to print the the outer hashmap using the following code

```
for (Entry<String, HashMap<String, String>> entry : mapofmaps.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            System.out.println(key);

      HashMap<String, String> value = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println(key + "\t" + value);
        }
```

I would like to iterate through the inner map. What would be the entryset variable there (??? in the code).

```
for (Entry<String, HashMap<String, String>> entry : mapofmaps.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                System.out.println(key);
    for(Entry<String, HashMap<String, String>> entry : ????.entrySet()){
          HashMap<String, String> value = entry.getValue();
                System.out.println(key + "\t" + value);
            }}
```

Is my logic for printing the hashmaps correct? or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: "Is my logic for printing the hashmaps correct?" No it isn't. when you iterate thru inner hashmap you obviously need another type for `entry` (because it contains another type of data).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It will be `entry.getValue().entrySet()`
so

```
 for(Entry<String, String> innerEntry : entry.getValue().entrySet()){
```

then you can use

```
    String key    = innerEntry.getKey();
    String value  = innerEntry.getValue();
```

---

It is worth mentioning that, this can also be done Using java 8 Streams and lambda expressions

```
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> mapofmaps = new HashMap<>();

    HashMap<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("map1_key1", "map1_value1");

    HashMap<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("map2_key1", "map2_value1");

    mapofmaps.put("map1", map1);
    mapofmaps.put("map2", map2);
```

---

```
     // To print the keys and values
     mapofmaps.forEach((K,V)->{                 // mapofmaps entries
         V.forEach((X,Y)->{                     // inner Hashmap enteries
             System.out.println(X+" "+Y);       // print key and value of inner Hashmap 
         });
     });
```

---

`mapofmaps.forEach((K,V)`  **:** This expects a lambda expressions which takes two inputs i.e Key (String) and Value (HashMap)

`V.forEach((X,Y)->{` **:** As this is applied on inner (`V`: fetched through previous foreach) hashmap so both Key and Value will be strings

Reference for further reading :

- [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)
- [Map foreach description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)

Answer (score 7):

A Straight forward example with data

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Apple", 10);
    map.put("Motorolla", 20);
    map.put("RealMe", 30);
    map.put("Oppo", 40);
    map.put("Sony", 50);
    map.put("OnePlus", 60);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ", Stock : " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

Using lambda expression

```
map.forEach((K,V) -> System.out.println(K + ", Stock : " + V));
```